# how do i give python input a value, i just don't know and understand

Tags: python, input

question, is it possible to get an input in python and give that input a value using another input?
I'd like something like:

```
x = input("input here: ")
# me writing, let's say, cheese
```

and the giving the previous input a value using another input.
Hope this isn't too hard for yo guys to understand, hope you can do something...

Comment: Do you mean something like `x = input("input here: ") x = input("another input : ")`?

Comment: So do you want to have a variable called `cheese` that will have some value?

Comment: better use dictionary for this.

Comment: Yes, i want the input (cheese) to have a value, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

An easy trick to do that would be to store both inputs in a dictionary with one input as key, and the other as value. For example, you can have something like this:

```
variable_value = input("Input a value")
variable_name = input("Input a name for this value")
variables = {}
variables[variable_name] = variable_value
```

In this way, when you want to access a variable, instead of using calling the name directly, you need to access it in a dictionary.

Of course this is not doing exactly what you want, but it can basically achieve mentioned funcionality.

Comment: Thank you for reacting, i know it was kind of a vague question, and if you spot a mistake in my English, i'm sorry, but i am dutch and not THAT good at English...

Comment: @Cheese_Fan haha no worries, me neither. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Oh, yes, just to be clear, this was what i was looking for (a friend helped me out):                                                                                                                 
text = {}

text[input('word: ')] = input('meaning: ')